# Visual Studio 2022 doesn't show IncrediBuild Build Monitor

Tags: visual-studio, incredibuild

I have recently updated my Visual Studio from 2017 to 2022 and IncrediBuild started to behave differently.

Previously, when I built my solution with IncrediBuild the "Build Monitor" opened as another view (just like Find/Output/Breakpoints/Bookmarks/etc. views) and I could easily track the build progress and address the errors from inside IDE's interface itself. This is how it used to look:

[image]

With Visual Studio 2022, however, this is not possible and even when I initiate the build and press to View->Build Monitor (as [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visualize-your-build-with-incredibuilds-build-monitor-and-visual-studio-2019/#how-to-invoke-the-build-monitor-display-as-well-as-incredibuild-acceleration-capabilities-from-within-visual-studio-2019) suggests) it doesn't open as a view inside IDE itself. The only option is double-clicking IncrediBuild's icon in the notification area:

[image]

But this is not as useful as it used to be because it doesn't sync build errors with the code editor in IDE. I mean that clicking next/previous error only shows the error message in the Build Monitor and I have to open the files and search for the lines of code with the errors manually.

Is it possible to make IncrediBuild extension to behave the same way in MSVS2022 as it was in MSVS2017?

I have "IncrediBuild Build Acceleration" installed on both versions of Visual Studio (2017 and 2022) and the extensions' configurations are identical as far as I can tell.

I have the following versions of VS/IncrediBuild/extensions installed:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.56 VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.56+33926.519

   - with IncrediBuild Build Acceleration   1.5.0.33
2. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.7.0 VisualStudio.17.Release/17.7.0+34003.232

   - with IncrediBuild Build Acceleration   1.6.0.7
3. IncrediBuild Agent Version 10.4.0 (build 11361)

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to install the add-in.  Run the Visual Studio Installer again and be sure to tick "Incredibuild - Build acceleration".  https://docs.incredibuild.com/win/latest/windows/visual_studio_add_in.html

Comment: @HansPassant, I have checked the installation of the extension before asking the question but I have just checked it again and I have "Incredibuild - Build acceleration" installed.

Comment: @a_girl, Can you share if you have found the solution or a workaround?

Comment: @Nitesh, I haven't yet. Now I simply don't use IncrediBuild that often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We asked Incredibuild support the same question. It's a bug on their side and due to several changes in VS2022’s GUI they say.

They will fix it, but it doesn't have priority.

Quote from support:

> We're looking at returning support for the integrated build monitor during the IB10 lifecycle, but it is not a specific part of our roadmap now and there's no timeline that I can share with you.

Their proposed solution is to use the Build monitor option in the agent settings:

[image: Build monitor option]